# как использовать несколько jquery в smarty

Tags: jquery, smarty

Есть 2 jquery, стандартный от смарти старой версии и новый, нужно подключить карусель owl, для нее нужен новый плагин, для всего остального стандартный, как можно решить эту проблему?

Пробовал это(не помогло)

```
<script>
 $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: смарти то тут при чем?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.1.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

И далее

```
(function($){
  $('#carousel').owlCarousel({})
})(jQuery_1_3_2)
```

Comment: [скрин](https://image.prntscr.com/image/jYV6z7fYTwSYDKhvJS0adQ.png) вот ошибки с консоли, не помогает данный способ

Comment: `cannot read data of undefined` - это может быть и не связано с jQuery